# R no error message when using undefined variable in the function

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I noticed that R will not raise an error when you pass an undefined variable to a function, if the corresponding argument is not actually used.

For example, suppose we have

```
testFunc = function(x=1, y=1) { return( x + 1 ) }
```

Calling `testFunc(x=2, y=z)` will give you the answer without raising an error.

Is this behavior designed on purpose in R or is this something that needs to be amended?

Comment: This is by design. If you never use a parameter inside a function, that value is never evaluated and will not trigger an error. R uses lazy evaluation for function parameters.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your explanation. I noticed this problem while I was reviewing my code. One of my function f has an argument y, but I actually used yy inside the function body. Before calling f I actually defined this yy variable. yy is visible to f even if it is defined after f. I guess I need to be more careful about these R features...